# Is it possible to check users bandwidth in frontend using iperf

Tags: javascript, java, iperf

I have frontend in js where you can type in `iperf` command and then `POST` it to backend in java. Then use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to check users bandwidth, is it even possible or it's just not how `iperf` works. My guessing is it is only possible to check server's bandwidth. 
TL;DR 
I want to to make online speed test using iperf

Comment: This is old, but might answer the question - https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/482

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for, just didn't know If it's doable thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the experimental Network API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/downlink